# How to add different icons for different cases?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I want to add different icons for different cases but don't know the syntax. I have already added a single icon for all cases but don't know how to add different or many icons. I have used 'fa fa-battleship to add a battleship icon here similarly I want to add different icons like car tree etc through different cases when level = 0 icon will be 'fa fa-tree' and when level = 1 then the icon will be 'fa fa-car'.

```sql
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
            when level = 1             then 1
            else                           -1
        end as status, 
       level, 
       "FIRST_NAME" as title, 
       'fa fa-battleship' as icon,
       "HUM_ID" as value,
        null as tooltip,
'f?p=&APP_ID.:9:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P9_HUM_ID:'||"HUM_ID" as link
from HUMAN_RESOURCES
start with MANAGER_ID is null
connect by prior HUM_ID = MANAGER_ID
order siblings by FIRST_NAME
```

How can I add different icons for different cases in this tree? And what should I do if I want to show a folder icon when the component is further driven into other components and a file icon when the component is not driven further?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data; a detailed English (not code) description of the logic you are trying to implement; an explanation of the issues/errors with your code; and the expected output for that sample data. We cannot help you add different icons because you have not (yet) described how you want to select alternate icons (or even what those icons are).

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement in your sql query to return a different value for the icon value in different cases. Example:

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
            when level = 1             then 1
            else                           -1
        end as status, 
       level, 
       "FIRST_NAME" as title, 
       CASE WHEN connect_by_isleaf = 0 THEN 'fa fa-folder' 
            ELSE 'fa fa-file-o' END 
            as icon,
       "HUM_ID" as value,
        null as tooltip,
'f?p=&APP_ID.:9:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P9_HUM_ID:'||"HUM_ID" as link
from HUMAN_RESOURCES
start with MANAGER_ID is null
connect by prior HUM_ID = MANAGER_ID
order siblings by FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: what should I do  if I want to show a folder icon when the component is further driven into other components  and a file icon when the component is not driven further

Comment: updated my answer. This is visible in the peudocolumn connect_by_isleaf